# html div center text between images

Tags: html, css, tags

I have the following (modified with valid code):

```
<div width:50%>
  <img height="30px" width="30px" src="some1.png"/>
  <img height="30px" width="30px"  src="some2.png"/>
  <span>A bunch of text that will wrap around to two or more lines</span>
  <img height="30px" width="30px"  src="some3.png">
</div>
```

My problem: I can't seem to be able to center the text between the images while being able to resize the browser window and get the span text to wrap but still stay in the vertically centered between the images down to a very narrow window where the text wraps from a single line to multiple lines. Also, I need to fill the parent div by right justifying the final image should the text be shore.

Comment: 1st. Make the code standard to avoid unexpected behavior.  2nd. Please provide a link example.

Comment: Modified code but no online example, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit tricky and doesn't have a straight forward solution. Basically you're asking to maintain the width of the span flexible/auto, based on the width of the window, while keeping the images at a fixed width.

Check out the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ubhvbh7o/4/)

HTML: (Also there were some html errors that I fixed.)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img height="30" width="30" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="image" />
  <img height="30" width="30" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="image" />
  <div class="container">
    <span>A bunch of text that will wrap around to two or more lines</span>    
  </div>
  <img class="last" height="30" width="30" src="http://placehold.it/30x30" alt="image" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   position: relative;
}

.container {
    border-collapse: separate;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: table;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}

span {
    border-collapse: separate;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 40px 0 5px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img.last {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but the last image wraps with the text in your jsfiddle. The idea is resize the browser window without losing the placement of the images on either side of the text and the text in the middle wrapping and centering.

Comment: This is ALMOST there! The only thing is when the text is short the final img doesn't go to the end of the parent div (see my example). Apologies for not clarifying that I want to fill the parent div (edited).

Comment: See edited answer. Please up vote & mark the answer as the solution. Thanks!